# What Need to Pass for Logout Passport Function

Tags: laravel, token, passport.js

Using Passport for Access Token and Refresh Token. For Logout function what should be Posted/Get and What will be the URL?

API Route:

```
 Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'api\LoginController@logout');
    });
```

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        return $this->loggedOut($request);
    }
```

1. URL: http://localhost:8000/api/auth/logout ???
2. What should be posted for this URL ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a prefix of **auth** then that should be a correct logout route. If not, remove **auth** from url.

**Token** should be present in **axios headers**, since the logout route is under **auth:api** middleware, and you will revoke it inside logout method.

**Code snippets as requested in the comment**

Once you login the user you add token to axios headers

```
axios.defaults.headers['Authorization']='Bearer ' + token;
axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type']='application/json';
```

When you make logout request

```
axios.get('/api/auth/logout')
    .then(response => {
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        localStorage.removeItem("token_type");
        delete axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'];
    }).catch(error=> {
});
```

And in your logout method in controller you revoke the user token

```
$request->user()->token()->revoke();
return response()->json([
   'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
]);
```

Comment: 1. URL: http://localhost:8000/api/auth/logout ???
2; What should be posted for this URL ?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the route? Are there any errors that you are getting?

Comment: I am not having problem with Route. Confused What should be posted for "logout(Request $request)"

Comment: You don't have to pass anything extra. It is a get request anyways. Only auth token needs to be present in axios headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `access_token` in `Authorization` header which you have got after successfully logged in.

Your logout route is protected by passport so When calling routes that are protected by Passport, your application's API consumers should specify their **access token** as a **Bearer** token in the **Authorization header** of their request.

For example, when using the Guzzle HTTP library:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/logout', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

from the doc [laravel passport passing access token](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#passing-the-access-token)